# How will you open Gmail from IT point of view?

Tags: gmail

EDITED:
During an interview, I was asked "What is the correct way to open the gmail web service from IT point of view?".
At that time I simply replied : "through chrome" . 
However I think there is more to it. What should be the correct way?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "open"?

Comment: open refers to "launch"

Comment: Could you please edit your question and try to make clear what exactly should be done? Open a web page? Read e-mails?